# Get the 2nd link value from a Div jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div and there's 4 links in it.

I want to get the 2nd link using jQuery.

```
$('div.thumbnails-b').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I see all those 4 links in the browser's console log. But how to get the 2nd link in the div?

Comment: Please provide your html.

Comment: It's too big.... I get all the links like this:

http://link1
http://link2

I want to link2

Comment: you should post the html that is related to that div only. Please update the question with that piece of html only

Comment: look at the docs for each https://api.jquery.com/each/ . The first argument to the callback is "index", which starts at 0. So when index == 1, it's the second element. Grab that one and exit. Or use selectors as suggested in the various answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('div.thumbnails-b').find('a').eq(1)`

See more: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the [n-th](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) element using jquery selectors (they start at index 1)

```
$('div.thumbnails-b').find('a:nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `eq`:

> jQuery( ":eq(index)" )
>
> index: Zero-based index of the element to match

So

```
$('div.thumbnails-b').find('a:eq(1)');
```

Or

```
$('div.thumbnails-b a:eq(1)');
```

This is the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).